# How to display tasks from database in a sharepoint gantt view

Tags: c#, sharepoint, task, gantt-chart

I have been searching for a while for a solution to display tasks that are stored in database in a sharepoint gantt view. All what I found on the internet is how to create tasks instantly while showing the gantt view. None was really explaining how to retrieve data from an sql server (or other) database table and actually displaying them on the gantt view.

Please, any kind of help is appreciated !

Comment: http://codesamplez.com/database/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-tutorial  how to read data from sql server , combine that with create a task and you are on the go

Comment: Shouldn't an external list solve this issue instead of copying each task to SharePoint?

Comment: @Thorarins thanks but it seems that the ambiguous part is not how to create the task but rather how to affect it to the gantt view which is created graphically

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh could you please refer me to a tutorial or explain more your idea ?

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163139.aspx) External lists in SharePoint can have an external data source (Excel file, SQL table, SAP system, etc.), but behave like normal SharePoint lists (with some restrictions). It should then be possible to just put a gantt view on that list.